# bash: /home/khawar/.local/bin/pip3: /home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/AAAIFace/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am installing TensorFlow using pip but due to some reason whenever I install anything any library using pip this error appears. Any solution? I already created a symbolic python of python3 but still getting the same error.

I do not want to use an anaconda, so I already deactivate the base environment.

**Traceback**

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu=2.1.0
bash: /home/khawar/.local/bin/pip3: /home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/AAAIFace/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop sourcing anaconda in your .bashrc/.zshrc

Remove the part below:

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
!! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/${USER}/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/${USER}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/${USER}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/${USER}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Where i have to put this script?

Comment: Check what you have in your $SHELL variable depending on that remove any conda blocks from you ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file.

Comment: sudo: /home/khawar/.bashrc: command not found. I am using Linux

Comment: @KhawarIslam : You try to execute `.bashrc` as an executable command. Don't do this.

Comment: Do I have to run the above command in the terminal?